# Why is the Set new visibility doesn't resets the hair's skeletal mesh visibility to be visible?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

The helmet is loaded when pressed a defined key and helmet is removed automatically by setting the remove on 2s delay.
The Problem when the helmet is removed, the hairs visibility doesn't sets to be visible while blueprint is set to restore the visibility.
`setvisibility` and `sethiddeningame` both are tested, none of them works.
How to fix it? any help appreciated.
[image: BLUEPRINT 1]
[image: BLUEPRINT 2]

Comment: You're always setting the variable to true for "Has Helmet?"  Is there anywhere you're setting it to false?

Comment: @Stephen Yes by default `Has Helmet` is fasle.
This is only true if the `num1` is pressed

Answer (score 0):

[image: SOLVED]

The Problem is solved, actually the node was not connected to the remove function.